# Parsing XML using the Cocoa API - please help a newbie :)

Tags: objective-c, xml, xpath

I need to extract specific contents from some XML for a project of mine. I am rather new to this so I first watched similar topics and read about XPath and xmlib2. I could not get it to work for my project, hence I have opened this question.

I would love if someone could state the general guidelines for:

1. What settings I need to change / do I need to install anything?
2. How to parse and extract specific elements (for example: I want to get the content of  content . How do i do that?)

Thanks alot for your help! I am sure I am not the only new-guy struggling with this, and an updated topic would be of great help for the community. :)

Comment: 1. This is not related to Xcode, 2. you may want to take a look at the `NSXMLParser` classx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using XCode AND you go with *NSXMLParser* for your parsing needs, then you don't have to install anything.  For answers to your parsing questions, check out the Mac Developer Library, specifically this article: [Event-Driven XML Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/XMLParsing/Articles/HandlingElements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002265-1001863).

Comment: this was exactly what i was looking for! i went through the developer docs but could not find it. thank you!